# how to clip/restrict the sinusoidal wave in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I wanted to create a sinusoidal waveform using pgfplots, which "clips" the top wave. I am attaching the code that I tried to do, but the wave form becomes smooth and offset from the node.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[very thick,->](0,0)to++(4,0)node[below right]{$t$};
\draw[very thick,->](0,0)to++(0,4)node[below left]{$V_{out}$};
\draw[magenta, dashed](0,3)node(vout){}node[left]{$V_{out1,CM}$}to++(4,0);
%\draw[cyan, dashed](0,3)node[left]{$V_{out2,CM}$}to++(4,0);
\begin{axis}[
        width=2.75cm, height=2.5cm,
        trig format plots=rad,
        enlarge x limits=false,
        xtick=\empty,
        axis lines*=middle,
        hide y axis,
        hide x axis,
        scale=3,        
%        axis x line=bottom,
        at={(vout.west)},
        anchor=west,
        xshift=3mm,
         xlabel=$t$,
        every axis x label/.style={
            at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},
            anchor=west,
        },
        ]

    \addplot [no markers,smooth, domain=0:6*pi, magenta] {(-sin(\x)>=0.5)?0.5:-sin(\x)};
%    \addplot [no markers,smooth, domain=0:6*pi, magenta] {(-sin(\x)>=0.5)?\empty:-sin(\x)};
%    \draw[dashed,black!80] (axis cs: 0,0) -- (axis cs: 2*pi,0);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

and the corresponding output shown below:

[image]

but I need a graph like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were absolutely on the right track. But you just used too few sample points which in combination with `smooth` caused the "overshooting". Thus, increasing `samples` (from default 25) to 201 yields the desired result.

(Besides that I simplified your code a bit ...)

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=left,
        xlabel=$t$,
        ylabel=$V_{out}$,
        every axis x label/.style={
            at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},
            anchor=north west,
        },
        every axis y label/.style={
            at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},
            anchor=north east,
        },
        ymin=-1.5,
        ymax=1,
        trig format plots=rad,
        enlarge x limits=false,
        xtick=\empty,
        ytick=\empty,
        clip=false,
        % moved common `\addplot` options here
        no markers,
        smooth,
        domain=0:6*pi,
        % increased number of samples to reduce "overshooting" caused from `smooth`
        samples=201,
    ]

%        \addplot [dashed,samples=2] {0.5};
        \addplot [dashed,samples=2,magenta] {0}
            node [at start,left] {$V_{out1,CM }$}
        ;
        \addplot+ [magenta] {(-sin(x)>=0.5)?0.5:-sin(x)};
        % (a bit simpler way to do what you want)
        \addplot+ [blue,dashed,restrict y to domain*=-1:0.5] {-sin(x)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Thank you, but I have one doubt. How to shift the entire graph in y-axis. And what does {0} signifies in this "\addplot [dashed,samples=2,magenta] {0}
            node [at start,left] {$V_{out1,CM }$}". Is it pointing to the origin of the wave?

Comment: Maybe first to the second question: When one (only) writes `\addplot {...}` then the part in the curly bracket is expected a (mathematical) expression, that in this case is `y=0`. Thus a horizontal line at y=0 is drawn. If you need the horizontal line higher or lower, just change the value.

Comment: To the first question: That depends on what you exactly mean by "shifting". E.g. you could add `xmin=-1` to the `axis` options to draw the y axis at x=-1 instead of presently x=0. Or you can change the `domain` given to the `axis` options to `0.5:6*pi` and add `domain=0:6*pi` to the options of the first `\addplot` command.